# ExtJs(4.2): Persist Time While Displaying Date time in DateColumn

Tags: date, datetime, extjs, extjs4.2

I have `datecolumn` in a `grid`.

I am getting value from backend in following format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`. I have to display it as `d.m.Y`. And While sending back I have to again send it as `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

My code is as following:

**Model**

```
{
    name: 'REA_LIT_URSPR',
    type: 'date', 
    dateFormat:'Y-m-d H:i:s.0'
}
```

**View**

```
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn',    
    format:'d.m.Y',         
    text: 'Ursp. LT',
    align: 'center',
    flex:1,
    dataIndex: 'REA_LIT_URSPR',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        format:'d.m.Y',
        editable: false
    }
}
```

---

Now issue is that if I get this value `2016-04-05 23:15:03.0`, it is displayed properly. But as soon as I click it to edit it(and cancel it without selecting new date), I lose the Time `23:15:03.0` and it is changed to `00:00:00.0`.

I want to persist this time, in case when user click on cell to change date but change his mind and click somewhere else without changing date.

I am using `Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing` for making grid editable.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or how can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS CellEditing plugin does not support "canceling" an edit by the user - whenever you click into the field and then leave, the field is validated, and if that does not fail, it is "edited". This is different in RowEditing, where a cancel button is shown that would cancel the edit and fire the `canceledit` event without validating the input.

So you would have to use the [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-beforeedit) and [`validateedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-event-validateedit) events on the CellEditing plugin. How to use them is described very well in the ExtJS docs, which documents how to access the date field, the record and the store all at the same time. Example code:

```
beforeedit:function( editor, context, eOpts ) {
  editor.oldTime = context.record.data.REA_LIT_URSPR;// Save old value.
},
validateedit:function ( editor, context, eOpts ) {
    if(editor.context.value == editor.oldTime) // Compare Values and decide
        context.cancel = true;                 // whether to save it or not

}
```

Comment: Thanks, You have been of great help as always. 
I got the value from the context object in before edit and then compared it with the editor.context.value to set value of context.cancel as you suggested.

Answer (score -1):

```
{
    xtype: 'datecolumn',    
    format:'Y-m-d g:i:s A',         
    text: 'Ursp. LT',
    align: 'center',
    flex:1,
    dataIndex: 'REA_LIT_URSPR',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        format:'Y-m-d g:i:s A',
        editable: false

    }
}
```

Ok so the problem is on column date format, maybe you lose a part of date because g:i:s aren't saved from the datecolumn.

I haven't tryed the code, but if it doesn't work try to create a new date format using these docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-parse    (same on extjs 4)

sorry for first answer, just not clear question

Comment: I don't have cancel and modify on click code. 
I just call store's sync method upon every selection. 
I already tried to save my value on 'focus' even and setting it back if date didn't change on 'blur' event, but I don't have any reference of store's record whose cell which was clicked (also i think is solution is not clean).

Comment: sorry if i try with questions but my reputation isn't high to comment your question, so i must send you answers to try the solutions

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Thing is that I don't want to show the time part to user so 'd.m.Y' is the format for front end.
In yours solution time is visible which is not what I want to achieve.